# Compilations of PoC of JavaScript vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, cve

I am a researcher looking for some proof-of-concept JavaScript vulnerabilities like XSS that exists in some website or JavaScript libraries in the past. Are there any compilations of them?

Comment: There are many lists on the internet about vulnerabilites in the web. One example is https://wpvulndb.com/ with thousands of vulnerabilites in Wordpress + Plugins.

Comment: @Lukas Thanks Lukas, that is very useful, let me know if you have more of them.

Comment: [cvedetails](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/opxss-1/xss.html) is another site. But really, you can just google it. "cve xss" or "xss poc" (maybe + some well known software) should give you plenty of results.

Comment: You've tagged your question with CVE, so you should know enough to find more on your own ;-) Just find any public CVE list and use the search function of the site to get as many XSS, SQLI, CSRF ... vulnerabilities as you like. One example with > 10.000 results:  https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=XSS

Comment: @Lukas Thanks Lukas, thanks for the great suggestion! I was thinking keyword like "javascript", "browsers", yours are definitely more direct!